# keras failed to import pydot

Tags: tensorflow, keras, graphviz, pydot

I'm trying to run the [Pix2Pix](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/generative/pix2pix.ipynb) tutorial for Tensorflow. I'm using the official docker container for this. This is how I start my container:

```
docker run --gpus all -it -p 8888:8888 --rm -v $PWD:/tf -w /tmp tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3-jupyter
```

I'm not able to get pass by this cell

```sh
generator = Generator()
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(generator, show_shapes=True, dpi=64)
# output -> Failed to import pydot. You must install pydot and graphviz for `pydotprint` to work.
```

I have tried also installing the `pydot` and `graphviz` using pip and also apt-get. Even if this libraries are installed I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and follow this [link](https://github.com/XifengGuo/CapsNet-Keras/issues/25)

In short:

- run these command on command prompt.

```
 pip install pydot 
 pip install graphviz
```

- From [website](https://graphviz.org/download/), download and install graphviz software

> Note: in install time, check "add to system path" option to add bin
> folder to path variable otherwise you should do it manually. restart
> your windows

Comment: Can you please share the exact command that worked for you? This line is too abstract: `install graphviz software from its [website][2]` Is this answer referring to my problem with the official docker container?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. does my edit solve the problem? Graphviz  is a software that needs to be installed separately.